# Unable to understand how redux dispatch is accessible

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to learn redux and the tutorial I'm following along has the following syntax in the userActions file

```js
export const loginUser = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
dispatch({type: 'something'})
}
```

However when we call the loginUser function (in another file) the syntax is like this

```js
this.props.loginUser(userData)
```

I was wondering where does the dispatch come from? Why **don't** we get `dispatch is undefined` for calling it in this manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dispatch` function is made available because you're using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), which is a redux middleware. And because of this middleware, your `action` is able to fire multiple `dispatch` to your `reducer`.

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch function` comes from `connect` function of [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect). `Connect` function receives `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

With `mapStateToProps`, redux map state from reducer to `this.props` of your component

With `mapDispatchToProps`, redux will call a function like `login`, after login redux will `dispatch` an action with some new states(optional) to let you know login success or failed. Those states will be passed into your component through `mapStateToProps`

Comment: the `dispatch` has nothing to do with `connect` because OP said he saw the `dispatch` on `userActions` file, not `component`

Comment: @Isaac dispatch he saw in `userActions` file is only a syntax for redux middleware understand those action. `dispatch` doesnot comes from redux thunk, it comes from `store` and `connect` help passing `dispatch` into those actions

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a state container which is used to have a global state which can be access from all over the project. so we have to inform the global container about our state changes such as create,delete and updates. To inform the changes we use dispatch and we provide a referring name called type. in some cases we pass the data also to dispatch with the referring name of payload.

the first function you wrote was trying to login with the user data. the function is needed to be called in login component. so we pass the function as prop to the login component. now the login function is in your props so simply call is as
`this.props.loginuser(userdetails)`